# adding a column to a sql table from other columns' values

Tags: sql

I have a sql table like this:

```
Name  | gender
-----------
John  | Male
Jane  | Female
Alice | Female
```

I want to add another column to the table that uses the other two columns in its content as follows:

```
Name  | gender   | Description 
----------------------------
John  | Male     | John is a Male.
Jane  | Female   | Jane is a Female.
Alice | Female   | Alice is a Female.
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Does that column need to be permanent? Maybe you only need to generate it when querying?

Comment: This is not something you want to be storing and can lead to data inconsistencies; create a *view* if you need this to be implemented in the database (do you?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MS SQL, you can use the following to generate a computed column. The contents of this column is calculated when it is selected.

```
ALTER TABLE Foo
ADD Description AS CONCAT(Name, ' is a ', Gender)
```

If you want the value to be stored on disk (calculated on insert/update), use the following statement

```
ALTER TABLE Foo
ADD Description AS CONCAT(Name, ' is a ', Gender) PERSISTED
```

You will generally want to use the first version if the column is selected less often than the other columns are updated. If the data is rarely updated, the second version is generally more appropriate